# Mentions of Valmiki Samhita

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, valmiki, ramanandacharya

Mentions of **Valmiki Samhita** in *scripture* and by *Acharyas* in their works.

> Valmiki Samhita is a text which falls under Panchratric text.

Answer (score 2):

Valmiki Samhita is considered as one of the most prominent scripture for the worship of Bhagvan Sri Ram and infact in this text alone for the very first time “Vishishtadvaita” has been quoted, this has also been quoted by many Great Acharyas and Scholars in their works. This Samhita falls under Panchratric text which is also mentioned in scriptures.

**Mentions of Valmiki Samhita:**

**1•** Valmiki Samhita has been itself quoted in Vishwamitra Samhita in Chapter 2 Verse 28, under the 108 names of Panchratric text, **Published from Kendriya Samskrit Vidyapeeth, Tirupati —**
[image]

Click Here: Vishvamitra Samhita (https://archive.org/details/ixTp_vishvamitra-samhita-by-undemane-shankar-bhatta-series-no.-13-kendriya-sanskrit-vidyapith-tirupa/page/12/mode/1up)

**2•** Sripad Karpatri ji in his very prestigious work **Ramayana Mimansa** has quoted this scripture under the special Samhitā texts which mentions Sri Ram Charitra:
[image]

**(-Rāmāyaṇa Mimansa Page No 688)**
Click Here: Ramayan Mimansa (https://archive.org/details/ramayan-mimansa-karpatri-swami/page/n764/mode/1up)

**3•** Published by Gita Press Gorakhpur in Kalyan Hanuman Ank by Sri Vaidehi Kant Sharan ji:
[image]

Click Here: Shri Hanuman Ank (https://archive.org/details/uQoN_shri-hanuman-ank-special-49th-year-edition-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n397/mode/1up)

**4•** In the work **Samskrit Vangmay Ka Brihad Itihaas** by Acharya Baldev Upadhyay, Valmiki Samhita has been put under Panchratric text:
[image]

Click Here: Sanskrit Vangmay Brihat Itihas (https://archive.org/details/11.-sanskrit-vang.-brihat-itihas-11-tantragam/page/n163/mode/1up)

**5•** By the author of world’s largest commentary on Ramcharit Manas known as **Manas Piyush**, Sri Anjani Nandan Sharan has quoted Valmiki Samhita in his commentary on Vinay Patrik —
[image]

Click Here: Vinay Piyush (https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.483928/page/n493/mode/1up)

**6•** In Rudra Yamala Uttara Tantra Dharma Aur Darsan by Dr. Ramashankara Mishra, has given the reference of Vishwamitra Samhitas Quoted Pancharatric text which includes Valmiki Samhita—
[image]

Click Here: Rudra Yamala Uttara Tantra Dharma Aur Darsan (https://archive.org/details/rudrayamalauttaratantradharmaaurdarsanramashankaramishraparimalapublications_202003_396_B/page/n67/mode/1up)

7• In Panchratra Samhitasu **by Sri Lakṣmī Narsimha Bhatt**, has put Valmiki Samhita under Panchratric text at 172 number —
[image]

Click Here: Pancharatra Samhitasu (https://archive.org/details/PancharatraSamhitasuGnanapadaSameekshanam/page/60/mode/1up)

8• Commentary on **Sripad Shankaracharya’s work named, Aprokshanubhutih** by Dr. C.A Shaila, published from Su-kṛtīndra Oriental Research Institute, Tammaṉam, Koĉci—

[image]
[image]

Click Here: SRISANKARACHARYAVIRACHITA APAROKSANUBHUTIH (https://archive.org/details/srisankaracharya0000drcs/page/50/mode/1up)

9• In the commentary of Prashnopanoshad known as Vaishnav Bhashya; **Sri Swami Vaishnavacharya** has quoted Valmiki Samhita:
[image]

(-Prashnopanishad pratham prashna)

**10•** F. Otto Schrader in his work “An introduction to Panchratra” has mentioned Valmiki Samhita as a text under Panchratra:
[image]

Click Here: Introduction to the Pañcaratra (https://archive.org/details/introtothepancar00shcruoft/page/n24/mode/1up)

Also there are many references like of Sri Ram Prasadacharya around 1680’s who quoted this Samhita as one of the most prominent text which talks about Lord Sri Ram in his “Dharm Sikhsha Patri”, also Jagadguru Ramanandacharya has quoted this text while having debates with opponent as mentioned in Acharya Vijay also Sri Ram Prapannacharya in his Commentary on Ananda Bhashya has quoted Valmiki Samhita, likewise their are many more references.

Click Here To Download Valmiki Samhita (https://archive.org/details/valmiki-samhita) (only samskrit)

Credit ~ Ram Rasik Quora
https://lordrama.quora.com/Mentions-of-Valmiki-Samhita-in-scriptures-and-in-works-of-revered-Acharyas